# Assign flag value based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like below

```
    groups|score|threshold|cumsum|
    A     |3    |4        |3     |
    A     |2    |4        |5     |
    A     |1    |4        |6     |
    B     |6    |5        |6     |
    B     |1    |5        |7     |
    C     |4    |4        |4     |
```

In the Dataframe I want to create a new column called top_flag. This new column will flag observation in the dataframe as fools;

1. Flag each observation whose cumsum less than threshold as 1. In this case only the first observation in the A group will be flagged.

2.Next, within each group, flag the first row that violates the condition above as 1. In this way, we can see that all the observation in group B violates the condition in (1) so will just flag the first observation in that group as 1 else 0. For C, there is only one observation and it violates our condition but since it is only 1 observation in that group we will flag it as 1 anyway.
My desired final dataset  should look like below:

```
    groups|score|threshold|cumsum|top_flag
    A     |3    |4        |3     |1
    A     |2    |4        |5     |0
    A     |1    |4        |6     |0
    B     |6    |5        |6     |1
    B     |1    |5        |7     |0
    C     |4    |4        |4     |1
```

Can anybody show me how to easily do this pandas?
My first try is as follows:

```
    #condition 1
    df1 =df[df.cumsum < df.threshhold]
    df['top_flag'] = 1
    #condition 2
    df2 = df[df.cum >= df.threshhold]
    #within each group rank cumsum in ascending to flag anywhere rank = 1 as 1 else 0.
    df2['rank'] =df2.groupby(['groups'])['cumsum'].apply(lambda x: x.rank())    

    df2['top_flag'] = df1['rank'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 1 else 0)
    df2 = df2.drop(columns = 'rank')
    df_final = pd.concat([df1,df22])
    df_final = df_final.groupby(['groups'])
```

I strongly feel like there is gotta be a slicker way to do this in pandas. Does anyone knows of a better way?

Comment: Does your code give you the result you are looking for? If yes, this is a better suited question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Did not know that exist, next time. However, whiles you are still here can you can you help or knows anybody that can help?

Comment: No, as far as pandas is concerned, this is on topic. But I need clarification. Point 2, you mention to flag the first row that violates the condition above. What condition are you referring to?

Comment: Flag each observation whose cumsum is less than threshold as 1. In this case only the first observation in the A group will be flagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, for the first condition, perform a simple series comparison. For the second condition, perform a `groupby` + `cumcount`, and take the row with `0` only. OR the two conditions to get `top_flag`.

```
df['top_flag'] = (
      (df['threshold'] > df['cumsum']) | df.groupby('groups').cumcount().eq(0)
).astype(int)

df

  groups  score  threshold  cumsum  top_flag
0      A      3          4       3         1
1      A      2          4       5         0
2      A      1          4       6         0
3      B      6          5       6         1
4      B      1          5       7         0
5      C      4          4       4         1
```